# How to compare two dictionaries with the same keys and update values with a condition in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, updates

```
d1 = {'a': 5, 'b': 8, 'c': 5}
d2 = {'a': 9, 'b': 4, 'c': 7}
```

I would like to update the values in d1 if the values in d2 smaller than in d1 to get a new dictionary d:

```
d = {'a': 5, 'b': 4, 'c': 5}
```

Comment: What was the difficulty you encountered when you tried to do this?

Comment: The issue seems to be resolved, please mark the answer as accepted to close it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
d1 = {'a': 5, 'b': 8, 'c': 5}
d2 = {'a': 9, 'b': 4, 'c': 7}

>>> dict([min(i, j) for i, j in zip(d1.items(), d2.items())])
{'a': 5, 'b': 4, 'c': 5}
```

`zip(d1.items(), d2.items())` to join the items in both the `dict`s, then just iterate over these items and select the `min` of both, make a dictionary with `dict` again.

Answer (score 0):

```
d1 = {'a': 5, 'b': 8, 'c': 5}
d2 = {'a': 9, 'b': 4, 'c': 7}

d = {k:min(v,d2[k]) for k,v in d1.items()}

print(d)
# {'a': 5, 'b': 4, 'c': 5}
```